# Is there any way to read 2 next lines into pattern space when a pattern is matched?

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following data file:

```
Name: ABC 
Address: 123, 4th Street,  
My County,
    
    
10009 Country. 
Age: 34 
Gender: Male
    
    
Name: DEF 
Address: 456, Orange Street,
    

North State,
    
45678 Country. 
Age: 68 
Gender: Female
```

---

Basically, each record is separated by 2 empty lines.
The problem is some "Address" will contain 2 empty lines too (see example above).

How can I replace the valid "2 empty lines" separator with say "#####", but leave the 2 empty lines in the "Address" field untouched (as is)?

Thanks.

I tried various "sed" commands with N options and "awk" commands, but nothing works so far :(

Comment: Update your question with expected output and your attempted code.

Comment: try:

    awk '/^$/ && NR > 2 {print "#####"; next} {print}' input_file

This command will print each line. If two consecutive empty lines are encountered (indicated by /^$/) and the line number (NR) is greater than 2 (to avoid the first two lines), "#####" is printed and the next line is processed.

Comment: Hi Liel, the problem is there are some "Address" fields that will also contain 2 empty lines.

Comment: See and act on [the first comment you got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298771/is-there-any-way-to-read-2-next-lines-into-pattern-space-when-a-pattern-is-match#comment132869268_75298771) so we can help you. The site exists to help people with their code so without code in your question it's likely to get closed as off topic. You already have downvotes (not mine)

Comment: As the record ends with `Gender` perhaps `sed '/Gender/{n;N;s/.*/#####/}' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each record ends with a `Gender:` line then you can do something like:

```
 awk '{if(NR<=n)next;print $0}/Gender/{print"######";n=NR+2}' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. I have also figured it out with "sed" with command sed '/^$/N;/^\n$/N;s/\(^\n\n)Name:/\1#####\nName:/' <file>.